# Android - Device's orientation change effect on X,Y Axis

Tags: android

I am currently trying out the Android Sensor library for screen rotation. Just wondering, initially the device's X-axis is pointing East and Y-axis is pointing North, but when the device's orientation changed(ie. from potrait to landscape), will the X,Y axis of the device also change?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same question and I made a simple app. The result is that the xyz axis will not change with a change in the device orientation.